# Get download Progress in Flutter using event stream

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a download progress indicator using CircularProgressIndicator in a Flutter app. The problem is that the last developer has implemented the download functionality using EventChannel and I need help with how to get the download progress data to use as value parameter for CIrcularProgressIndicator. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Create channel:

```dart
const eventChannel = EventChannel('name_of_channel');
```

## 2. Get broadcast stream for receiving events on this channel:

```dart
final progress$ = eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream() as Stream<double>; // this stream emits values from 0.0 to 1.0.
```

Method `Stream receiveBroadcastStream ([dynamic arguments])` also accept a parameter `arguments`, you can pass based on native code.

## 3. Build Widget based on progress stream:

```dart
StreamBuilder<double>(
    initialData: 0,
    stream: progress$,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final progress = snapshot.data;
        return CircularProgressIndicator(value: progress);
    }
)
```

Hope this solves your issue.